# Android : Can i call my onresume() inside onpause().?

Tags: android

I want that just before my application goes in background the user should get a dialogue box asking if i want to exit this application.
And if user selects no then i want that he should be resumed to my application again instead of launching another application.
So,is it possible in android?
One solution can be like this that i call **onresume()** inside **onpause()** or **onstop()**.But can this be done.
Please help me out.

---

My code is like this:-

```
public void onPause() {
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
       builder.setMessage("Do you want to quit");
       builder.setCancelable(false);
       builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            MytestprojectActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });

       builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

       AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
       alert.show();
       super.onPause(); 
}
```

first i basically want to see if it runs on calling of onpause() or not.
so, what i got is that it pauses my activity, goes to another activity and when my activity restarts then it shows me the dialogue box. m i missing something.?

Comment: you can override back button or home button pressing and do anything you want there. onpause() is reserved for saving state of your app and onstop() is reserved for finalizing it, so calling onresume() instead would a bad solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748763/call-alertdialog-onstop-onpause

Comment: All this being said, it is extremly bad app behavior doing this.
You should rather save your states of your game / app in onPause and then restart them in onResume.

Comment: @user1049280 what u said is ok. but if suppose my user in using keyboard and through certain combination he gets my activity on background then.? I want that if my activity is running the it should only run and it should not go in background i.e. i want my application to be running or completely destroyed. i donot want it to go in background. So, is it possible then?

Comment: @andersmetnik ok what you said is fine. but i dont want my application to store anything. i just want that either it should be in running state or destroyed state.

Comment: @shrikant please see my code below and suggest if i am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple:

```
public void onBackPressed() {

       final Builder builder = new Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.caption);
        builder.setMessage("Do you really want to exit?");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourActivity.class);
                     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

                     startActivity(intent);
                     YourActivity.this.finish();
                     dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                            final int which) {
                                                  dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
```

}

This should solve your problem :)

UPDATE: When your app is going in background, onPause() will definitely be called. So write this dialog box inside your onPause(), and onClick of negative button call startActivity() with intent as Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT.

Comment: thanks for your answer but if u read my comment above u would come to know what exactly i want. So, if u can give me the answer that would be helpful.

Comment: no it is not working. if i write it inside onpause() then it is not showing any dialogue box, instead it is switching over as normal onpause call. :(

Comment: Are you calling dialog.show() method? You must be missing something, coz its running at my side.